# How do I get overlapping probability?

Tags: probability, stata, mathematical-statistics

I have something like this:

```
Case I

         A
|-----------------|
         |------------------|B

Case II
                     A
            |-----------------|
|---------------------|
          B
```

And the following numbers:

```
     Total generated by A            Total generated by B as seen by A
A            1000                                    139

     Total generated by B            Total generated by A as seen by B
B            300                                      60
```

I am trying to get the probability that the events generated by A and B will overlap (or rather I am trying to look at the probability that the pair A-B will generate events that overlap). I am doing it the following way:

```
    Total generated by B as seen by A + Total generated by A as seen by B
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  Total generated by A + Total generated by B
```

Is this correct or am I missing something? Or is there a better way to characterize the relation between A and B?

Finally, if I have thousands of such pairs, what can I derive about the system?

Comment: Just to clarify, is this the type of data: (A) Of 1000 supermarket trips on which Tide was purchased, Crest was purchased on 139. (B) Of 300 supermarket trips on which Crest was purchased, Tide was purchased on 60. If so, do you have other information (e.g. to establish whether this is a higher than lower than normal rate)?

Comment: That's an interesting analogy. You are correct. However, unfortunately, that is the only piece of information I have available. I am not sure how to use this information to say something about pairs of such combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have different numbers for overlap (139 and 60) I have to assume you have different samples.  So, let's keep the same proportions as 139/1000 and 60/300 but adjust so we have the same number of overlap events (in this case we will adjust to 139).

I'm going to stay with the Tide/Crest example because it helps (me at least) to stay concrete. After we adjust to we have the same number in the overlap cell, we can determine the total number of trips with either A or B (1556), of which 139 overlap.  So the probability that the events generated by A and B will overlap is .089.

If this matches conceptually what you are looking for, then we're at the stage where the example can be converted to formulas.   I'm not sure this is an answer to your question, but I'm posting it as an answer so I can paste the picture in.

[image]